# install Ubuntu 13.10 on my notebook

Tags: drivers

It's ovi from Bangladesh.

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my notebook which is [Compaq CQ-41 209-TU](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&product=4114985).

On the official site I find drivers only for windows. What after installing Ubuntu? Without drivers I can't use WiFi , LAN, Bluetooth, the webcam.

What should I do?
Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi drivers,lan etc will be installed automatically.

If not then goto additional drivers from the dash by Pressing The meta(windows) Key.